# Code stops all withdrawals even when its not supposed to

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

So I was supposed to implement a piece of code that prevents a user from withdrawing money from their Savings account more than once a month but unfortunately, I have run into a wall and cannot figure out how to solve this. My code prevents withdrawals even if the only transaction was a deposit.

```
def okToWithdraw(acc: SavingAccount) -> "bool":
    """Compares two dates then gives the ok"""
    # reads lines of dictionaries and appends the to a list
    myList = openfile("accountTransactions.txt")
    # today's date
    tim = str(date.today())
    # filters through the file so that only transactions
    # from the same account are forwarded
    found_list = search_dic_list(myList, "AccID", acc.acc_ID)
    # if not found, green light and Withdrawal can proceed
    if not found_list:
        return True
    else:
        # here is the problem code
        dic = found_list[len(found_list) - 1]
        if days_between(tim, str(dic["TransTime"])) >= 30:
            return True
        return False
....
...

def search_dic_list(myList: "list", key: "str", item: "str") -> "list" or None:
    """Searches a dictionary list by its key for a certain value
    returns the found value as a list
    None is it doesnt exist"""
    found_value = []
    found = False
    for dictionary in myList:
        if dictionary[key] == item:
            found_value.append(dictionary)
            found = True
    if found:
        return found_value
    return None
```

Any help would be appreciated
To note: Each and every transaction has a unique ID that is mostly identical but increments itself

```
trans_id = str(acc.acc_ID) + method + str(tim) + "_" + str(count)
# acc.acc_ID = account class ID ex. "1234_Sav"
# Method = a string ex "_WD_"
# str(tim) = time
# str(count) incrementing index
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are your withdrawals have any identification which could help find difference between other transactions?

Comment: The transaction ID is there, thankfully. so that should be of some help.
I simply hit a wall because no matter what I was trying it was throwing errors back at me

Comment: You searches take only account_id, you can find withdrawals by check "-" in operation sum

Comment: I am sorry, I dont understand what you mean :(

Comment: I want to say that you can select all withdrawals by operation type. After withdrawal account balance is lower than before, but another transactions grow up balance

Comment: umm, I am kind of a beginner so I have no idea how to implement that. I don't even quite know what it means. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Can you show search_dic_list function body? Maybe I can help you

Comment: What a returning list look like? Can you give a sample?

Comment: [{'Customer': '1234', 'AccID': '1234_Sav', 'TransID': '1234_Sav_Dep_2021-12-17_1', 'Balance': 1234.0, 'TransTime': '2021-12-17', 'Amount': 1234.0}, {'Customer': '1234', 'AccID': '1234_Sav', 'TransID': '1234_Sav_Dep_2021-12-17_2', 'Balance': 1357.0, 'TransTime': '2021-12-17', 'Amount': 123.0}]

Sorry, you can't withdraw from this account at the moment.

this is the output

Comment: We need withdrawal example and we can implement small function for you task]

Comment: please get rid of `search_dic_list`. Dictionaries are meant to be searched by key, that's what they do for you

Comment: if type(acc) == SavingAccount:
                ok = okToWithdraw(acc)
                if not ok:
                    print("\nSorry, you can't withdraw from this account at the moment.\n")
                    break
            amount = input("\nPlease enter amount to be withdrawn : ")
            amount = Number_Verification(amount)
            if not amount:
                print("Sorry, that is not a valid number")
            else:
                ......

Comment: @Pynchia i have a list of dictionaries and I had to separate them somehow.......

Comment: We need example of withdrawal transaction, and then we can separate it from other transaction

Answer (score 0):

You can implement small function for find withdrawal in found_list and change some code:

```
def okToWithdraw(acc: SavingAccount) -> "bool":
    """Compares two dates then gives the ok"""
    # reads lines of dictionaries and appends the to a list
    myList = openfile("accountTransactions.txt")
    # today's date
    tim = str(date.today())
    # filters through the file so that only transactions
    # from the same account are forwarded
    found_list = search_dic_list(myList, "AccID", acc.acc_ID)
    found_withdrawal = find_withdrawal(found_list)
    # if not found, green light and Withdrawal can proceed
    if not found_withdrawal:
        return True
    else:
        # here is the problem code
        dic = found_list[len(found_list) - 1]
        if days_between(tim, str(dic["TransTime"])) >= 30:
            return True
        return False
def find_withdrawal(transactions: list)->datetime:
    pass
```